# Use external lib with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I want to use this lib in my app : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-animated-headlines

But i don't know how to import it.

First, i add these lines in my angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/jquery-animated-headlines/dist/css/jquery.animatedheadline.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/jquery-animated-headlines/dist/js/jquery.animatedheadline.min.js"
  ]
```

Second, i install jquery `npm install jquery --save`

Then, i import jquery : `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Finally i copy/paste their example :

TS :

```
constructor () {
   $(function() {
     $('.selector').animatedHeadline();
   })
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="selector">
  <h1 class="ah-headline">
    <span>My favorite food is</span>
    <span class="ah-words-wrapper">
        <b class="is-visible">pizza</b>
        <b>sushi</b>
        <b>steak</b>
    </span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

I get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animatedHeadline is not a function`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong ...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include your libs in angular.json. Import it just where u need it.

First, install the packages:

```
npm install jquery jquery-animated-headlines --save
```

Then, go to the desired component and import them:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery' // in case u haven't imported it globally.
import * as animatedHeadline from 'jquery-animated-headlines;


@Component()
...
constructor () {
    $(document).ready(() => $('.selector').animatedHeadline())
}
```

Comment: `import * as animatedHeadline from 'jquery-animated-headlines';` does not work : `Cannot resolve definitions for module 'jquery-animated-headlines'`
In my node_modules directory i have a folder with this name :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it to work, but there must be a better way. I created a new project using @angular/cli version6.

```
npm install --save jquery jquery-animated-headlines
```

In the `angular.json` file, add `"node_modules/jquery-animated-headlines/dist/css/jquery.animatedheadline.css"` to the styles array.

Update the `app.component.html` to:

```
<h2 #foo>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-animated-headlines';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('foo') fooElement: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    $(this.fooElement.nativeElement).animatedHeadline();
  }
}
```

Now things should work at this point, but don't seem to due to the way that the plugin library is written. I also had to go into the `node_modules/jquery-animated-headlines/dist/js/jquery.animatedhealdine.js` file and update the way that it is importing jquery.

The file comes looking like:

```
(function($) {
  .
  .
  .
}(jQuery));
```

and I had to update it to:

```
(function (factory) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    }
    else if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    }
    else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($, undefined) {
  .
  .
  .
}));
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to handle this in Angular and this won't work well with an automated build system, but for local development it should work fine.

**UPDATE**

The way to get this working in your application is as follows.

In the `angular.json` file add:

```
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/jquery-animated-headlines/dist/js/jquery.animatedheadline.js"
```

to the scripts property.

In your component, use `declare var $: any;`. For example:

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('foo') fooElement: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    $(this.fooElement.nativeElement).animatedHeadline();
  }
}
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-animated-headlines).